# Выполнить одно из двух правил – то которое больше всего подходит

Tags: php, kohana

При регистрации пользователя и **не** совпадении паролей в полях «*password*» и «*password_confirm*», у меня отрабатывает функция

```
public static function get_password_validation($values)
{
    return Validation::factory($values)
        ->rule('password', 'min_length', array(':value', 8))
        ->rule('password_confirm', 'matches', array(':validation', ':field', 'password'));}
```

Которая находится в стандартном модуле «"*…\SiteDesigner1\www\modules\orm\classes\Model\Auth\User.php*"»
И выводит сообщение:

```
«*Поле "password_confirm" должно совпадать с полем "password"*»
```

Мне как-то англ. слова тут не нужны.
Если я у себя в своем модуле «*user*» напишу правило:

```
'password_confirm'     => array(array('matches', array(':validation', 'password_confirm', 'password')),
```

То в html соответственно выводится 2 предупреждения:

```
Поле "Повторить пароль" должно совпадать с полем "Пароль"
Поле "password_confirm" должно совпадать с полем "password"
```

Такой вопрос:
Что нужно переделать? Или каким образом можно «забить» функцию public static function get_password_validation($values)? (чтоб выводилось только ПОЛНОСТЬЮ РУССКОЕ сообщение)

*Заранее спасибо.*

Comment: А нет в валидаторе какого-нибудь параметра message? Или условия, позваоляющего не выплнять валидацию, если имеются ошибки?

Comment: Сейчас посмотрел, ничего такого там не нашел